# Configuring 2D Boy framework in Visual Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, 2d-games

How do I configure the 2D Boy rapid game framework inside Visual Express C++ 2010 IDE?

I am new to both c++ and visual studio (mainly program with Java/go on Linux) so I am not too familiar with setting up a project in visual studio.

The framework is setup for Visual Express 2008 but I cannot get it to work on the 2010 version.

The code and README can be found here:

http://2dboy.com/public/framework.zip

Comment: If it has been prepared for 2008, you take responsibility for the conversion. What's not working, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to C++ and Visual Studio, it may be a difficult start. Anyway, here are the steps to use the 2dboy framework with Visual Studio 2010:

1) install the DirectX SDK. You can find some information here [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx). If you choose the June 2010 SDK and face the "S 1023" error, you might want to have a look at this [Known Issue: DirectX SDK (June 2010) Setup and the S1023 error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/12/09/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error.aspx)

2) download a new VS 2010 solution I have built from here: [2dboyframeworkvs2010](http://www.softfluent.com/smourier/download/2dBoyframework_VS2010.zip) and unzip here somewhere on your disk. There were a lot of small problems I fixed because the original version was built using VS 2008 and an old version of the DirectX SDK.

3) follow the readme.html found in the solution root (I have modified the original with some extra information). You will need to download a library called [irrKLang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/). and place it in the *libs* directory in the unzip folder.

4) compile the solution. You should now have a demo1.exe and demo2.exe in their respective directory. Copy irrKLang.dll and SDL.dll aside these and run them. The demo2.exe is an asteroid demo with sounds.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, Simon. Ca marche!